# Sync data between web server and mobile in android

Tags: android, web-services, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am making an application where all the data is stored in the server. When using application for the first time the data is downloaded in the **SQLite** form. Then if I use the application later the only time web services need to called is to check whether data is update in the server. If yes, the updated data will be added to the **SQLite** table and if no, the data will be fetched form the saved **SQLite** database in the memory. Any tutorial or code will help.

Comment: I've answered your question, please check my answer and tell me what you think

Comment: @MonzerYaghi : Yes I've gone through it. Please see my comment on your answer.

Comment: check my second answer @gautam

Answer (score 0):

In the following code I'm getting data from an online server through a php page, the data is filled in java arrays :

**Class.java**

```
try
        {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        httppost = new HttpPost("http://youronlinewebsite/yourpage.php");
        try
        {
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Appname",appname));//Appname is the name of the column in your online database
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Applink",applink));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8"));
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
        {
        entity=response.getEntity();
        if(entity !=null)
        {
            InputStream instream=entity.getContent();

            try
            {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(convertStreamToString(instream));
                arr=jArray;
                titlearray = new String[arr.length()];
                linkarray=new String[arr.length()];

                myDbHelper.openDataBase();              
        //// boucle for         
                for(int i =0; i<arr.length(); i++)
                {
                    try
                    {

        JSONObject json_data = arr.getJSONObject(i);

        titlearray[i]=json_data.getString("Appname");
        linkarray[i]=json_data.getString("Applink");
        //downloadFolder();     



 myDbHelper.Insertinfo(titlearray[i],linkarray[i]);//function that inserts data in sqlitedatabase


                 //     
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        a=ex.toString();
                    //  Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),ex.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }


                myDbHelper.close();   //closing the database helper instance            
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),ex.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }

        }
        else
        {

        }


        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
    //  a=ex.toString();    //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),ex.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }






        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

**The function convertstreamtostring**

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
{


BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
try
{

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  sb.append(line + "\n");
}
}catch(IOException e)
{

}
finally
{
    try{
        is.close();
    }catch(IOException e)
    {

    }
    }return sb.toString();



}
```

Comment: Thank you. But this is half way done. This will call the web services and then will download the data into SQLite. But major part is I don't want to call the web service again and again. I want a trigger which will be set and check the change in the web services. If there are no changes, the application will read data from mobile and if there are changes, the application will first download and over-write the data. Can you do something for that?

Comment: check my second answer @gautam

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps :

- In your online database create a field called update, and insert in it the value "0"

  - In your application, create a service in which your write a process
    that runs in the background of your application
  - The process will do the following : it will check all the rows in your online database, when the value of your "update" field is 0 it won't make any changes and the application will read data from mobile, otherwise if there is a change (the value in the field is 1) it will take all the data from the row and update it in your SQLite database
  - To do the process for example every 1 minute, write the code below :

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, Updateservice.class);
      PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
      AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
      alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 60000, pintent);

Don't forget to add the following line in you manifest file :

```
<service android:name=".Updateservice" />
```